# Determine if SPD workflow is saved or published?

Tags: designer-workflow, versioning

How do I know if a SharePoint Designer workflow is only saved instead of published?

If another user saves the workflow, will I see their changes?

Answer (score 0):

On the List Settings or Library Settings page, in the Permissions and Management section, click Workflow Settings.
If you see the workflow instance here means workflow is published.